# Liferay Freemaker: how to get Request object in template?

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-theme

I am using Liferay 6.2 and freemaker for web content templates. I need to get request object in template. When I try to use `${Request.getRequest()}`  it throws error `Expression Request is undefined`. 
Full code here

```
<#assign userService=utilLocator.findUtil('my-portlets', org.test.service.UserService')>
 <#if userService.isUser(Request.getRequest())>
     <h1>is User</h1>
 </#if>
```

My handling method for userService

```
public Boolean isUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //some logic
    return true;
}
```

How I can get Request object in freemaket ftl template?

Comment: `$request` is an implicit object available in templates.

Comment: However, if you want to get `httpServletRequest` object, you can get it by:  `#set ($serviceContext = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal").getServiceContext())
#set ($httpServletRequest = $serviceContext.getRequest())`

Comment: Thank you! But can you post your answer in more expanded way with a little example? @ParkashKumar

Comment: Did it worked in you case?

Comment: No, it falls with `Unknown directive: #set` @ParkashKumar

Comment: Ohhh, you are using `ftl` language in templates, then you can use, `<#assign>` instead of `#set`.

Comment: You can use it like: `<#assign $serviceContext = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal‌​").getServiceContext()>
<#assign $httpServletRequest = $serviceContext.getRequest()>`

Comment: Now `Expression $portal is undefined` :( @ParkashKumar

Comment: Check for your property `freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=` in `portal.properties` and ensure it doesn't add `$portal` to its list.

Comment: Here is complete list of [***Implicit Objects & Variables***](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity)

Comment: And here is the [***Answer***](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/34142230#_19_message_34310408), that matched your question.

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker variables are case sensitive and don't start with the `$` sign (like in velocity).

Use the `request` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the request variable like in

```
<#if request.getParameter("something")??>
```

I find this file always useful

https://github.com/agmip/liferay-portal-impl/blob/master/src/com/liferay/portal/freemarker/FreeMarkerVariablesImpl.java

Also, the use of $ is probably causing you some issues there, as it is not used as it is in velocity..

Answer (score 0):

Simply use: themeDisplay.getRequest()

```
<#assign cookies = themeDisplay.getRequest().getCookies() />
<#list cookies as cookie>
  ${cookie.name} = ${cookie.value}<br>
</#list>
```